# Fundamental theorem of algebra in modular arithmetic

Tags: modular-arithmetic

suppose you have a polynomial $P(x) = a_0+a_1x+...+a_kx^k$.
How can you prove that at most $k$ numbers satisfy $P(x) \equiv 1 \mod n$ ?
To me this looks like the fundamental theorem of algebra, however, in modular arithmetic. Yet, I don't see why the theorem would apply here as well.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You mean $P(x) = 0 \pmod{n}$, I guess.

Comment: Does it really make a difference? Why would the constant $a_0$ matter?

Answer (score 4):

This is only true if $n$ is a prime.

If you take $n = 15$, for instance, the polynomial $x^{2} - 1$ has the four roots $1, 4, 11, 14$ modulo $n$.

When $n = p$ is a prime, you exploit the fact that $\mathbb{Z} / p \mathbb{Z}$ is a field, and recycle the usual proof.

I wouldn't call it the *fundamental theorem of algebra*, though, as that refers to the fact that a non-constant polynomial splits in linear factors in $\mathbb{C}[x]$.